# Images of a familiar object in $\mathbb{R}^3$ mapped to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by Cantor/Peano/Hilbert

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, curves

The proofs that, e.g., the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^3$ 
is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^2$,
map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ via some scheme: Cantor's interleaving decimals, the Peano curve, the Hilbert curve, etc., generalized to
higher dimensions.

I would like to see images of some familiar object in $\mathbb{R}^3$—say
a sphere or a cube—mapped to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
It is common to illustrate the mappings the other way, e.g., showing how
the Hilbert curve fills a unit square.
But I am interested in the reverse, to help intuition and
to better understand the effect of the mappings on an object.
I suspect $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ would not be illuminating,
which is why I ask for $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Can anyone point me to such images?

Comment: The results are generally not even drawable, because bijections $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ cannot be continuous. So the image of a solid object would be a rather weird subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: What are the properties that you want from such a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$? Do you want it to be continuous (a projection would do), or do you want it to be a bijection (which cannot be continuous)? I think one important reason they only talk about $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is that many points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are images of several points in $\mathbb{R}^2$; this cannot be accomplished the other way around.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Seeing that weird subset is what I have in mind. Seeing that it is weird emphasizes the lack of continuity.

Comment: @PedroM.: A (noncontinuous) bijection. I want to see an object shattered and distributed.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: What if, say, it both the set and its complement are dense in $\mathbb R^2$? How would you draw (or see) that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I guess then just a gray blur. Perhaps that is the only image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

** **UPDATE!** ** I revisited my old code and generated the following two pictures.

The first picture depicts the mapping of three spheres, each of radius 0.15, from the cube $[0,1]^3$ to the square $[0,1]^2$, where the spheres are centered at $(0.5,0.5,0.5)$ (red), $(0.2,0.5,0.5)$ (green) and $(0.2,0.2,0.2)$ (blue), respectively. I use the same mapping based on Sierpinski curves as described in my original post below.

[image: spheres]

The second picture depicts the mapping of three cubes, each of sidelength 0.3, from the cube $[0,1]^3$ to the square $[0,1]^2$, where the cubes are centered at $(0.5,0.5,0.5)$ (red), $(0.2,0.5,0.5)$ (green) and $(0.2,0.2,0.2)$ (blue), respectively.

[image: boxes]

---

**Update 2:** As you guessed, mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is not very illuminating. Here is the mapping of the standard test image ["Lenna"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) to 1D via the Hilbert curve:

[image: lenna]

---

**My original post:**

I made a few images related to this a few years ago. I didn't map objects in $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$, but rather I mapped the RGB color space to a two-dimensional picture.

Here is an example. To imagine what a (topological) ball maps to you could for example focus on where the bright red colors map to.

[image: sierpinski 3D to 2D RGB]

To be precise, each point $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ in the picture corresponds to an RGB-color $\varphi(x,y)=(r,g,b)\in[0,1]^3$, defined by $\varphi=\alpha\circ\beta^{-1}$, where $\beta:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ is the space-filling [Sierpinski curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_curve) (note: although $\beta$ is not invertible, its preimage has a unique element for each pixel in the image), and $\alpha:[0,1]\to[0,1]^3$ is a three-dimensional analogue of the two-dimensional Sierpinski curve (note: I chose one out of many possible natural generalizations of the two-dimensional curve; there seemed to be no canonical choice).

What the image looks like is very dependent on the choice of bijective functions. The image above is the most visually pleasant one I produced. Here are a few others:

1. Same as above but mapping HSV space instead of RGB space.

[image: sierpinski 3D to 2D HSV]

2. Using the Hilbert curve $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ and a three-dimensional analogue of it:

[image: 3D to 2D - hilbert_2(x,y)=hilbert_3(+r, +g, +b)]

3. Same as above but with the HSV color space instead.

[image: 3D to 2D - hilbert_2(x,y)=hilbert_3(+h, +v, +s)]

The Z-curve (equivalent to interleaving decimals), Peano curve and Schoenberg curve produced quite ugly pictures (sorry I don't still have them).

Comment: Your most recent update, showing the RGB spheres/cubes fractured and scattered, is exactly what I was seeking---Thanks!

Comment: It is interesting that there is no discernable "roundness" to the mapping of the three spheres.

Comment: more please :) see also https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/allrgb-hilbert-curves-and-random-spanning-trees/